# WatiN choosing the correct event string to use with FireEventNoWait for an input textfield

Tags: c#, events, input, webbrowser-control, watin

I want to get the input value of an `<input type="text">` element, on the fly (while it is being typed) and implement a search method with it as parameter.

I have this piece of code:

```
_window.Frame(WatiN.Core.Find.ById("a_frame"))
    .TextField(WatiN.Core.Find.ById("an_element"))
    .FireEventNoWait("event_string", other params);
```

What event would you think is the best suited for this? I have some thoughts on `KeyPressed` or `KeyUp`, but I'd like some other opinions for this matter? I have searched for `TextChanged` and some similar `Event`, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are we to assume the above code isn't working, or? If nothing else works you could always do a do loop right after the text box gets focus, do loop would contain these:

```
Sleep 100
Doevents
```

And of course after every 100 ms break and a Doevents, you can check to see if .value has changed, and if so, query your search. When the text box looses focus, you stop the loop.

You are using the webbrowser control, right? And you want to d this using the webbrowser control as opposed to JavaScript? Because, you can get keyup keydown events through the webbrowser controls eventing system, and that would be a better way to do it, but I'm not clear on the who what when where why of what your doing :)

Comment: Well, the functionality of the project isn't the same anymore, but I think that it would work anyway. The project is far away from that, so I don't have the chance to try your solution, I'm sorry... :(

Comment: @Souvlaki does this mean the problem is solved, or that the solution is no longer needed? if you have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: I don't need that piece of code, I redesigned it. So, I'm not able to test the solution. Thanks for your interest.